Correct matrix multiplication and 2D affine mapping using scipy
I have two sets of 2D data A and B I have to assume that there is a 2×2 matrix M and a 2x1 column vector c such that:
B = M*A + c + e
With e being the Gaussian error (mean of 0 and variance of sigma^2).
My goal is to estimate the matrix M and vector c for which the sum of squared distances between B and the predictions is minimized.
I am not sure how to do it in the right way. So far, that's what I've done:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([
    [0, -6],
    [0, 6],
    [-6, 0],
    [6, 0],
    [-3, -3],
    [-3, 3],
    [0,0],
    [2, -2],
    [2, 4],
    [-3, 0],
    [-5, -3],
    [2, 5]
])

B = np.array([
    [0.45070423, 0.52288732],
    [0.125, 0.5625],
    [0.1754386, 0.15789474],
    [0.200489, 0.55012225],
    [0.30769231, 0.32451923],
    [0.1375, 0.45],
    [0.19935691, 0.46302251],
    [0.32142857, 0.53571429],
    [0.12765957, 0.53191489],
    [0.15246637, 0.30269058],
    [0.2247191, 0.20224719],
    [0.14379085, 0.55882353],
])

# MAPPING : getting M and c

def error_function(params):
    # Unpack M and c from the flat parameter array
    M = params[:4].reshape(2, 2)
    c = params[4:]
    
    predicted_B = (A @ M) + c

    # Calculate the sum of squared distances
    return np.sum(np.sum((predicted_B - B) ** 2, axis=1))

# Perform the optimization
initial_guess = np.zeros(6)
result = minimize(error_function, initial_guess)
M = result.x[:4].reshape(2, 2)
c = result.x[4:]

# Getting predictions
predicted_B = (A @ M) + c

print(predicted_B)

In this implementation, I am not strictly sticking to the mathematics that I introduced before the code. I am doing (A @ M) + c instead of (M @ A) + c. The reason is that I am not sure how to implement it with column vector instead of row vectors. Anyway, is the result the same ? How could I modify my python code in order to implement exactly what I wanted to implement and be 100% consistent with the mathematics that I introduced earlier ?
Secondly, I am not dealing with the Gaussian error in my code because I am not sure if I have to. Is it implicitly done in the minimize function of scipy ?


Anyway, is the result the same ? How could I modify my python code in order to implement exactly what I wanted to implement and be 100% consistent with the mathematics that I introduced earlier ?

The problem with this approach is the size of the matrix you'll get out. When you multiply a m x n matrix by an n x p matrix, you get an m x p matrix as a result.
If A is on the left side of the multiplication, then you're multiplying a 12x2 matrix by a 2x2 matrix to get a 12x2 matrix. This is the size of B. This is fine.
On the other hand, if A is on the right side of the multiplication, then you have a problem. The result of the multiply must be 12x2. This means that M must have a first dimension of 12. The second dimension of M must match the first dimension of A. So M must have dimensions 12x12.
This means that you're estimating a lot of parameters. When you estimate lots of parameters, you get less certain about any single parameter, because there are lots of ways to get the same answer.
I think the way you have it now is fine, and is the normal way to describe linear regression. Usually you have the parameters you're trying to estimate on the right side of the matrix multiply.

Secondly, I am not dealing with the gaussian error in my code because I am not sure if I have to. Is it implicitly done in the minimize function of scipy?

No, SciPy is not doing anything with the residuals of your regression. It is only aware of the loss function you've defined.

Thanks !
And what would happen if I handle the predictions one by one in a loop in the loss function (and compute the loss and store it in a "total" variable that I return at the end) ? It would be (2x2) X (2x1) and the result would be a (2x1) which is what I want. I don't need to compute the 12x2 in a one shot, my goal is just to map the two arrays element-wise (A[1,:] => B[1,:], A[2,:] => B[2,:],... for instance in my code) and be able to map future (x,y) coordinates with the M and c parameters that I estimated.
Regarding the gaussian error: how can I include that in my loss function ?

" It would be (2x2) X (2x1) and the result would be a (2x1) which is what I want." Right, that would work. "Regarding the gaussian error: how can I include that in my loss function?" You don't need to. Performing an ordinary least squares regression already minimizes the variance of the error term.

I implemented it and it gives the same results at the very end (the predictions for B). Is it expected ?

You're doing the same computation, so I would expect the result to be the same.
